# Create script based on Integromat scenario

Tags: make.com

I'm not really sure how to ask this, but if I used Integromat to integrate APIs between two platforms, is there any way to create a hostable script from that? So that I am not dependent upon Integromat, but instead would include the script on a server or as part of a web app.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no

I haven't seen anything in Integromat that allows you to export their flow as a script. You can bind 2 APIs together and trigger that flow based on your conditions or time. Seems like if they allowed this - it would damage their business model.